# test ansible roles with molecule and boto3

Tags: python, ansible, aws-sdk, aws-cli, molecule

I have `ansible roles` that creates servers, S3 buckets, security groups ... and I want to establish some unit testing using `Molecule`.
After some researches, I found out that `Molecule` is using `Testinfra` to run some assert commands on the remote/local host. That can work for my roles that create some servers like `apache2`, `nginx`.. but how about the other roles that are just creating some other aws resources like `load balancers`, `autoscaling groups`, `security groups`, or just `s3 buckets`? in this case, there will be no host nor instances.

It would be easy to make tests by `Unittest` and `boto3` and call the AWS API, but my question is can I use `molecule` only and fire up an `EC2 instance` everytime I want to test my role of security group and then do something like this :

```
def test_security_group_has_80_open(host):
    cmd = host.run('aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-names MySecurityGroup')
    return_code = cmd.rc
    output = cmd.stdout
    assert output.contains('"ToPort": 80')
```

That `EC2 instance` would have `AWSCLI` installed. Is this a correct way ? Is it possible to test all type of roles by `Molecule` by firing an `EC2` that runs `awscli` calls ?

Comment: This is almost too broad, but I can offer some tips here. Molecule's acceptance testing does use Testinfra by default, but if you need different resources for your tests it can also make use of Goss and possibly Serverspec. You should indeed be able to use EC2 for your Molecule test platform. One of the problems you are encountering is that Molecule assumes you are doing software provisioning with Ansible (best practices). What you are doing is better suited for an infra provisioner (Terraform) which is why you are encountering issues with Molecule/Testinfra acceptance test intrinsics.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment or else I would, but to speed things up you can configure Molecule to not manage the create and destroy sequences.  And use the `delegated` driver with the converge playbook having `connection=local`.  This way you can simply just create the the security group using the role without provisioning instances and use boto3 to confirm your changes are correct.

This way you only need your test environment to have the proper keys available to make the API calls using boto instead of also worrying about whether or not the EC2 instance does as well.